# Removing few columns -- boosting SQL performance, but

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have a long SQL [here (with explain plan)](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=1-6YyQvx4cFqU4PHRsPWEjFegFpYp9hvPd66QcyDxJ1Y&hl=en&authkey=CKeM76EB).  Removing 5 columns out of 200 columns made this SQL returned in 20 seconds.  But once these columns are added back -- the query hangs.

I noticed the EXPLAIN PLAN is almost the same, except that after adding back -- the parallelism is happening (PX COORDINATOR -- PX RECEIVE & SEND, etc are found in explain plan).

Any suggestions?

**I run "ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL QUERY;" prior to running slow SQL. And now is fast.
Any idea how can I track back --where the parallelism could happen by adding few columns?**

Comment: What are the data types of the five columns you removed?

Comment: Yes, can not be answered without those. COuld it be that basically ;) The rmoved columns are hugh blob / Tex fields?

Comment: hello, thanks for your comment. Data type is varchar2, it's short one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without all the table definitions, it is hard to say.

I suspect you are hitting table elimination - that where a table isn't actually needed to satisfy a query it can be ignored. So if you don't actually need a column from T29, then it won't bother to join it. It requires various constraints to be in place so that it can logically determine it doesn't need the join.

Where the columns are added in, then it needs to do extra work, which tips it over into a parallel plan which it thinks will be faster. It isn't always right, especially with large numbers of tables where a small mis-estimate on one can be massively magnified.

I'd add the columns back in, disable the parallel query and look at the plan from there. Check the predicates and see if the estimates it is coming up with for rows/cardinality seem correct.

Comment: Hi Gary Myers, thank you for your valuable comment. All what you said are makes sense. I have generated the explain plan -- for all column & disabled parallel query, and update (at last page) of the same document in the link above. But i could not understand about "Check the predicates and see if the estimates it is coming up with for rows/cardinality seem correct." Appreciate if you could give further details. Thanks